# concrete5 doesn't recognise theme

Tags: directory, themes, concrete5

Just started with concrete5 but the documentation needs a lot of work.

I am trying to make a theme from scratch and testing it locally with XAMPP. This is my folder structure:

```
/
/application
/concrete
/packages
/themes (wasn't there when I installed concrete, made the dir myself)
/updates
```

I placed my theme inside the `themes` folder. Its structure is as follows:

```
/css
/fonts
/img
/includes
/js
/default.php
/description.txt
/view.php
/main.css
/thumbnail.png
/typography.css
```

Yet still the theme is not visible in the options. I'm lost. I'm using version 7.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a description.txt in your theme folder.

In the description.txt should be something like:

```
My theme 
This is a description of my theme
```

Where 'My theme' is the title of your theme and the line below the description of the theme.
Theming has not changed much between version 5.6 and 5.7 .

Source: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/designing-for-concrete5/building-a-concrete5-theme/converting-an-html-template-to-a-concrete5-theme/

**EDIT**

Don't forget, with the new version of concrete5, you place your custom themes in:
application/themes/

quote from source:

> Create a directory for your theme in the webroot/application/themes/
>   directory. In your theme's directory (e.g.
>   webroot/application/themes/urbanic/)

Comment: My bad. I actually *do* have a description in there. Forgot to add it to my op. However, it's still not working.

Comment: Editted my original answer. You need to put your custom theme in application/themes . in concrete5.6 and below, the website folder was the folder where you override/added custom items. In the new version you override/add custom items in the application directory.

Comment: Ah, that was the culprit! I really enjoy Concrete, but it's documentation is not very well accessible in my opinion. Might need to look for another simple CMS. Thanks!